# SQL Alter table failure on constraint

Tags: sql

My SQL is very out old, looking for some help with this error.

> The alter table statement conflicted with the check constraint "ZYZ". The Conflict occurred in table A column DESCRIPTION

```
ALTER TABLE A_A
ADD CONSTRAINT ZYZ
CHECK (((LTRIM(RTRIM([DESCRIPTION)))+'A'=([DESCRIPTION+'A') AND [DESCRIPTION]<>''));
```

I get this is a data issue, but not sure what to look at...

Comment: Well you have data in the description column that is failing the constraint you are trying to add.

Comment: I get that, I don't understand the constraint. As I didn't write it. I believe it's a blank value? As the table can't be null. I've found 2 blank values

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? That is invalid standard SQL

Comment: there should be no spaces on the left and right side of description and also description should not be blank

Comment: What is the data you are going to replace with blank value so that i can suggest the solution

Comment: Some of the square brackets aren't closed...

Comment: What do you  mean  with  ((LTRIM(RTRIM([DESCRIPTION)))+'A'  please explain what your trying to do ..  and if you are using mysql  tag properly

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name   thanks for the tip .. I had misread (and wrong answer too) many thanks